# How can I find Application Indicator ID's?

Tags: indicator, panel

I want to change the display order of several apps in the top panel of Ubuntu 11.10 (logging into Unity 3D) but I am amazed that there appears to be no easy way to do this.  However, I have read that the following file controls the display order:

```
/usr/share/indicator-application/ordering-override.keyfile
```

Further details here: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/how-to-change-application-indicators.html

At present I have the following top-panel apps installed:

- Radio Tray
- My-Weather-Indicator
- Choqok (a Twitter client)
- System monitor Indicator
- Classicmenu Indicator

In order to carry out the steps in the above link I need to know the correct Application Indicator ID for each of the above apps.  How can I find these?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the IDs should just be the commands used to launch the applications. Another possible way to figure it out would be to use `dconf-editor` and go to desktop -> unity -> panel and look at the list in systray-whitelist. That's assuming you have whitelisted everything with the ['all'].

Answer (score 0):

ref:
[How does one find out which application is associated with an indicator icon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185991/how-does-one-find-out-which-application-is-associated-with-an-indicator-icon)

Bookmark:
[How can I find Application Indicator ID's?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72946/how-can-i-find-application-indicator-ids/190411#190411)

This script

```
qdbus --literal   com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar                  \
                 /com/canonical/Unity/Panel/Service                \
                  com.canonical.Unity.Panel.Service.Sync           \
| sed -e 's/[^{]*{\(.*\)}\]/\1/' | sed -e 's/\[[^"]*/[/g'          \
| sed -e 's/\[\(\(\("[^"]*"\|[^,"]*\), \)\{4\}\)[^]]*,\([^,]*\)\]/[\4, \1]/g' \
| sed -e 's/\[\([^,]*\, \)\("[^"]*",\)/[    \1\2                  /g'  \
| sed -e 's/\[ *\(....,.\{24\}\) */[\1/g'  | sed -e 's/\], \[/]\n[/g'  | sort -n -k2
```

will list the matching ap/id's from left to right. For details see
[How does one find out which application is associated with an indicator icon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185991/how-does-one-find-out-which-application-is-associated-with-an-indicator-icon/187521#187521)